# Split data into time periods with the least number of NAs

Tags: r, date, dataframe, data.table, subset

I need to split my data into 3 different time periods, but I want to do it in a way where I have the least number of gaps (missing data) for each of the Y. Here is my data:

```
Data <- data.frame(
  Y = c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10),rep("C",10),rep("D",10),rep("E",10)),
  X = c(sample(seq(as.Date('2017/03/01'), as.Date('2017/09/01'), by="day"), 10),sample(seq(as.Date('2017/03/01'), as.Date('2017/09/01'), by="day"), 10),c(as.Date('2017/05/02'),sample(seq(as.Date('2017/05/01'), as.Date('2017/09/01'), by="day"), 9)),sample(seq(as.Date('2017/03/01'), as.Date('2017/09/01'), by="day"), 10),c(as.Date('2017/05/03'),sample(seq(as.Date('2017/05/01'), as.Date('2017/09/01'), by="day"), 9)))
)
```

Splitting it into 3 equal time periods would look like:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(Data$Y ~ Data$X,,
       panel = function(x, y) {
         panel.xyplot(x, y)
         panel.abline(v=c(as.Date('2017/05/01'),as.Date('2017/07/01')))
       })
```

[image]

In this case if I define the first period as, 2017/03/01 to 2017/05/03, instead of 2017/04/30, I wouldn't have an NA for the group C and E in the first period, which is what I want.

So I want those 3 periods to be:

- period 1: 2017/03/01 to 2017/04/30
- period 2: 2017/05/01 to 2017/06/30
- period 3: 2017/07/01 to 2017/09/30

But it can be up to 10 days flexible with the start/end of those periods. Is there any way to do this than looking visually?

Comment: If you create sample data involving random numbers, such as `runif()`, `rnorm()`, or `sample()`, please, uses `set.seed(<some_value>)` to make the data reproducible. Otherwise, your analysis and expected result depends on data which may look very different for other users. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are two boundaries that we can shift, each within an interval of 10 units, there are 21x21=441 options. That seems small enough to brute-force (or is this a simplified dataset and is your actual problem larger?).

Anyway, here is some very suboptimal code that does what you want:

```
Data <- data.frame(
  Y = c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10),rep("C",10),rep("D",10),rep("E",10)),
  X = c(sample(seq(as.Date('2017/03/01'), as.Date('2017/09/01'), by="day"), 10),sample(seq(as.Date('2017/03/01'), as.Date('2017/09/01'), by="day"), 10),c(as.Date('2017/05/02'),sample(seq(as.Date('2017/05/01'), as.Date('2017/09/01'), by="day"), 9)),sample(seq(as.Date('2017/03/01'), as.Date('2017/09/01'), by="day"), 10),c(as.Date('2017/05/03'),sample(seq(as.Date('2017/05/01'), as.Date('2017/09/01'), by="day"), 9)))
)

split1 = as.Date('2017/05/01')
split2 = as.Date('2017/07/01')

library(dplyr)
argmin=[i,j]
minimum = 999

for(i in seq(-10,10))
{
  for(j in seq(-10,10))
  {
    df = Data %>% group_by(Y) %>% summarize(period1 = sum(X<(split1+i)),
                                       period2 = sum(X>=(split1+i) & X<(split2+j)),
                                       period3 = sum(X>=(split2+j)))
    if(sum(df==0)<minimum)
    {
      argmin = c(i,j)
      minimum = sum(df==0)
    }

  }
}

cat(paste0("period 1: 2017-03-01 to ",split1+argmin[1]-1,"\n"))
cat(paste0("period 2: ",split1+argmin[1]," to ",split2+argmin[2]-1,"\n"))
cat(paste0("period 3: ",split2+argmin[2]," to 2017-09-30 \n"))
cat(paste0("Total NA's: ", minimum))
```

Output:

```
period 1: 2017-03-01 to 2017-05-03
period 2: 2017-05-04 to 2017-06-20
period 3: 2017-06-21 to 2017-09-30 
Total NA's: 0
```

Comment: If you create sample data involving random numbers, such as `runif()`, `rnorm()`, or `sample()`, please, uses `set.seed(<some_value>)` to make the data reproducible. Thank you.